# Using get_option() for check box field

Tags: options

I am trying to have a check field saved to database. it works . but in get_option i am passing the default value. but even if disable the checkbox(value 0) the field shows as ticked ..this is my code

```
<?php     
 $fields_default = array(
                0 => array(
                    'id'             => 0,
                    'checkbox_check' => '1',
                ),
                1 => array(
                    'id'             => 1,
                    'checkbox_check' => '0',
                ));

            $orderdescider = get_option('fields_new', $fields_default);

            foreach ($orderdescider as $checkfieldstatus) {
               if (isset($checkfieldstatus['id'])) {$id = $checkfieldstatus['id'];}
                if (isset($checkfieldstatus['checkbox_check'])) {$checkbox_check = $checkfieldstatus['checkbox_check'];} else { $checkbox_check = '0';}
                ?>

                <li class="sortable-item flexit">
                <div class="form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" name="orderdescider[<?php echo $id; ?>][checkbox_check]" value="1"<?php checked(isset($orderdescider[$id]['checkbox_check']));?> />
                 </div></li>
                <?php

            }
```

please help thanks

Comment: I'm unable to replicate your code, I get the following error code: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$orderdescider' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Could you paste all your code, so that I can take a look at it?

Comment: @RemziCavdar actually the array was not closed, please have a check now

Comment: Yes I saw that you were missing a semicolon, also you did't initalize your id variable like this: $id = '';

Comment: O'm sorry, but your code is not finished. You didn't even try yourself didn't you? See the rules: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @RemziCavdar i actually did, my code was a long one that's why i simplified it and ended up in these typo..i have updated the question

Comment: This site is not for questions that require professional hands-on involvement like overly complex and specific things (known as work for me for free)

Comment: Okay, only this time, but if I spend more than one hour I will flag this post.

Comment: @RemziCavdar hey buddy,if you notice any errors & if u could tell me that's a lot of help for me. it is an easy thing, but i have made a mistake somewhere and i am not able to see it..please do not spend more than 5 minutes on it ..it's a request

Comment: @RemziCavdar actually the code is working fine for me. just the problem is defult value checkbox is always in enabled coditions,..if i save to database then it works with values that is saved

Comment: Okay, so what is the issue? If I check a field and I go back I get an error.

Comment: In your questions, it's a good thing to tell people what you're trying to accomplish so that we could help you faster and better.

Comment: @RemziCavdar Issue is when get_option(), takes the values from the $fields_default, Even though check field is value is 0 , in the check box shows enabled(which means 1)....this is some what complected stuff i have build with this.i will be using this to arrage the fields in the custom post type ..this code is being used in a admin menu , and the data is being saved to database from there

Comment: I also get Notice: Undefined variable: value_new

Comment: Also why do you complicate things by using PHP short tag/code? This is not managble, I recommend doing everything written out, see my code: https://github.com/Remzi1993/wp-jquery-updater

Comment: You should write things out.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I get help you out with your coding style, so that it is more readble, see: https://pastebin.com/Eimh4RZ5

Comment: @RemziCavdar okay thanks i will keep this in mind while coding :)

Comment: @RemziCavdar the mistake was in `checked(1 == $orderdescider[$id]['checkbox_check']);` thanks

Comment: Okay, you're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not exactly answer the question, but let's see the issues with your code:

1. If you want to save the data in the same format as the default value (`$fields_default`), then:

   1. Start your `foreach` like so: `foreach ( $orderdescider as $i => $item )`.
   2. Then inside that `foreach`, `$id` and `$checkbox` should always be set and defined like so:

      ```
      $id = isset( $item['id'] ) ? $item['id'] : '';
      $checkbox_check = isset( $item['checkbox_check'] ) ? $item['checkbox_check'] : '';
      ```
   3. And use the appropriate value in the *field's `name`*:

      ```
      <input type="hidden" name="orderdescider[<?php echo $i; ?>][id]"
        value="<?php echo $id; ?>">

      <input type="checkbox" name="orderdescider[<?php echo $i; ?>][checkbox_check]"
        value="1" ...>
      ```
2. For the `checkbox` fields, you can use this format when writing the markup:

   ```
   <input type="checkbox" value="{value}"<?php // wrapped for clarity
     checked( '{value}', '{current/saved value}' ) ?> ...>
   ```

   so in your case, it would look like this:

   ```
   <input type="checkbox" name="orderdescider[<?php echo $i; ?>][checkbox_check]"
     value="1"<?php checked( '1', $checkbox_check ) ?> ...>
   ```

   where `1` is the `{value}`, and `$checkbox_check` is the `{current/saved value}`.

   (See the [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/checked/) for more details about using the `checked()` function.)

Hope that helps, and here's the full `foreach` code I used for testing: (I omitted the field's `id`, but make sure to use *unique* values)

```
foreach ($orderdescider as $i => $item) {
    $id = isset( $item['id'] ) ? $item['id'] : '';
    $checkbox_check = isset( $item['checkbox_check'] ) ? $item['checkbox_check'] : '';
    ?>
    <li class="sortable-item flexit">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="hidden" name="orderdescider[<?php echo $i; ?>][id]"
              value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
            <input type="checkbox" name="orderdescider[<?php echo $i; ?>][checkbox_check]"
              value="1"<?php checked( '1', $checkbox_check ) ?> class="form-check-input">
        </div>
    </li>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Hello ,  i am having a problem with same code , it is not getting saved in the database for some reason , will it be possible to have a check at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/319648/checkbox-with-get-option-not-working